# Supervisord log file is not created in given path

Tags: supervisord

I have the following in my `supervisord` configuration:

```
[program:nodejs]
command=node server.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/user/logs/nodejs.err.log
stderr_outfile=/home/user/logs/nodejs.out.log
```

I don't see log files being created in `/logs` directory. I see that temporary log files are created in `/tmp/nodejs_some_random_string.log`. What am I am missing in order to have log files created properly as specified in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supervisord has no configuration key with `stderr_outfile` - check out [child-process-logs](http://supervisord.org/logging.html#child-process-logs)

use `stdout_logfile` or `stderr_logfile`

Try like this:

```
[program:nodejs]
command=node server.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/user/logs/nodejs.err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/user/logs/nodejs.out.log
```

[see example configuration](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=stdout_logfile#program-x-section-example)

Comment: Thanks! My eyes didn't catch the typo.